Electrical switch with two black wires, one red wire and two white wires connected
I’m trying to replace my old electrical switch with a new dimmer switch for my lights. The existing switch controls the light for two light fixtures in the same room.
When I opened up the electrical switch, I see two white wires connected at the back, two black wires, going into the same  end on the existing electrical switch, and the red wire connected to the other end of the switch. How should I connect this to the new dimmer switch? It’s a Leviton DSL 06.
Should I join both the black wires from the wall and connect to the end which on the switch which reads BK, And connect the red wire from the wall to the end which reads RD. I probably don’t have to do anything with the neutral white wires and there’s no earthing wire seems to be connected to the metal box at the back.
Please advise. Attaching a picture of the existing set up.


When you separate the two blacks do you lose power to other  receptacles or lights?

Yes! I just found that. The two black wires are hot only when joined together! How is that possible? @NoSparksPlease

With the two blacks wirenutted together as in the picture, with no switch in the box and power on, do one of the lights illuminate?

Yes it does turn on the lights

You were smart to pay close attention to how the old switch was wired. You connect this switch the same.
This is a basic switch loop. The two blacks go to the terminal marked black and the red to the other. As you suspected, the white wires aren't involved.
It seems that the switch box is metal possibly with armored cable, so if you don't see a ground coming into the box you should connect the ground directly to the box the same as the old switch was connected.
As mentioned below - also make sure that the bulbs are dimmable.

Thank you @honeydo. I tried the same. The light does come on ... But I am unable to switch it off!! :) The light stays on Continuously. Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

If you're using LED bulbs and the switch is not set up or wired properly it may allow a small amount of current to leak through causing the LEDs to stay on. The DSL 06 has a switch for selecting the type of bulb. Assuming your using LED make sure it's set to LED. If the switch is properly set you might want to use a non-contact voltage tester or meter to make sure that the black wires are the hot feed and the red is your switch loop. Sometimes the colors are reversed. Make sure that the always hot lead is connected to the BK screw, regardless of color.

@HoneyDo also, if bulbs are LED OP should confirm that they're dimmable LED!

@Huesmann is correct. Make sure the bulbs are dimmable. Some are not.

The light fixture is an Led fixture which is definitely dimmable

@satishnair you have packaging stating that the fixture is dimmable?

Yes. Dimmable LED Flush Mount Ceiling... https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0CNCRWXS9?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share

I tested the wires with a voltage tester. The black wires when connected together starts beeping and the red one does not. I'm really confused now.

@HoneyDo you mentioned that the DSL 06 has a switch. I couldn't find it.

Here is a link to the bulb mode switch instructions. For LED the Mode switch should be set to the A position.          https://az188720.vo.msecnd.net/product-downloads/leviton-dsl06-1lz-instruction.pdf

Thanks. It's on mode A
